# Overriding in Flash IDE

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, overriding, timeline, dispatchevent

I'm trying to override dispatchEvent(), with no success in the Flash IDE.  Reviewing [Adobe docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/statements.html#override) on the method, it should simply be:

```
override function name()
```

As demonstrated by [Grant Skinner](http://gskinner.com/blog/archives/2008/12/making_dispatch.html), this is commonly and easily performed:

```
override public function dispatchEvent(evt:Event):Boolean {
    // code here
}
```

And while a thorough google search will repeat this syntax successfully used in Class files, doing so inside timeline code, natively in the Flash IDE is proving impossible.  The first issue being that the use of `public` throws the error `1114: The public attribute can only be used inside a package.`

That was obvious, however upon removing that, running the following (on the first frame of a new .fla file):

```
override function dispatchEvent(evt:Event):Boolean {
    trace(evt.type);
    return super.dispatchEvent(evt);
}
```

results in this error: `1024: Overriding a function that is not marked for override.`

[Documentation on this error](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/compilerErrors.html#1024) implies that I failed to prefix the identically named function with the `override` statement, but obviously that's a fallacy, and I'm left flabbergasted as to what the solution may be.

To be clear, we know a class file will work, but that's an irrelavant issue.  How do we get `override function dispatchEvent()` working in timeline code?

Comment: You probably can't do it from timeline code. You would probably have to switch from timeline code to having a "Document class" that would extend MovieClip, which in turn extends EventDispatcher, so there is a  dispatchEvent function to override.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only override class methods of the class you extend(the base class).
This follows the rules on inheritance.
When you extend a class you inherit all of its methods. Overriding a method allows you to restructure that method. Accessing a method and overriding it are 2 different things.

```
public class SomethingSomething extends Event{
  public function SomethingSomething ( ):void{
  }
  override public function dispatchEvent(evt:Event):Boolean {
    trace(evt.type);
    return super.dispatchEvent(evt);
  }

}
```

Comment: Wow... I just assumed the FLA document was a MainTimeline class, which I also assumed it inherited from [MovieClip](http://berniesumption.com/software/files/2010/10/DisplayObject_subclasses.jpg).  Is the document class a blank canvas then?

If true, this would certainly explain this issue.

Comment: Of course its true. However you can create a Main class and use that for your document class and have that extend what you need. what it all comes down to is you need to create a class to override a function of another class.

Answer (score 0):

dispatchEvent() is public, and your code is defualting to the default namespace. You neeed to do 
    override function dispatchEvent(evt:Event):Boolean

Comment: Epsdz: I'm assuming your reply was accidentally cut short, but the namespace should be the same, as I understand it.  As [Senocular points out](http://www.kirupa.com/forum/showthread.php?223798-ActionScript-3-Tip-of-the-Day/page5#post_1890503), "Anything defined as public can be accessed anywhere by anything."  Regardless, to be sure, trying `use namespace public;` at the head of the document does not resolve the issue, as one might assume.

Answer (score 0):

1.the following is a class

```
    package{
        import flash.display.MovieClip
        public class myClass{
            public function myClass(){
                // constructor code
                trace("this is constructor")
                waitToOverride()//trace this is overrided code of waitToOverride
            }
            static function waitToOverride(){
                //wait to override
                trace("this is original code of waitToOverride")
            }
        }
    }
```

2.the following use in flash IDE.Some object in library link ActionScript class(C):myClass.Then type the following code in object's MainTimeLine

```
    function waitToOverride(){
        // this will override myClass's waitToOverride method.
        trace("this is overrided code of waitToOverride");
    }
    waitToOverride()//this is overrided code of waitToOverride
```

ps. juse do it,you will understand what I mean.
Edit by Niauwu
http://blog.yam.com/celearning/article/28409939